# Visual Studio 2017 shortcut Eclipse equivalents

Tags: .net, eclipse, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

I have strong muscle memory for Eclipse shortcuts. I'm currently jumping into .NET development and Visual Studio 2017, which mean learning dozens of new shortcuts and leaving the comfort zone.

I would love a plugin which enables idiomatic Eclipse key bindings in VS to maximize my productivity. However, I found out this kind of extension is only available for Visual Studio Code, not for VS 2017. Is this truly the case?

What are equivalences for following Eclipse shortcuts in VS 2017?

General:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (Quick-fix, super useful swiss army knife)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (Organize imports)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Refactor/rename)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (Maximize/restore selected window)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (Close editor tab)

Navigation and searching:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Search/open file by pattern)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (Search/open type by pattern)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (Advanced search inside project)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (Inspect call hierarchy)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd> (Traverse previous locations)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (Search/jump to class attribute/method by pattern)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (Format code automatically)
- <kbd>F3</kbd> (Jump to declaration)

Debugging:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> (Switch between editor/debug views)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (Toggle breakpoint)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (Disable/Enable all breakpoints)